# Calculating the posterior distribution - missing dependency

Tags: statistical-inference, bayesian, bayes-theorem

I am reading an old paper from https://www.jmlr.org/papers/volume1/tipping01a/tipping01a.pdf.
In that paper, specifically, Equation 10 says
$$
p(w|t,\alpha,\sigma^2) = \frac{p(t|w,\sigma^2)p(w|\alpha)}{p(t|\alpha,\sigma^2)}.
$$
However, it seems that in order for the above equality to hold, we need to assume that
$$
(*) \quad \frac{p(t,\sigma^2|w,\alpha)}{p(\sigma^2|\alpha)} = p(t|w,\sigma^2).
$$
This is because
\begin{align}
p(w|t,\alpha,\sigma^2) &= \frac{p(w,t,\alpha,\sigma^2)}{p(t,\alpha,\sigma^2)}
= \frac{p(t,\sigma^2|w,\alpha)p(w,\alpha)}{p(t|\alpha,\sigma^2)p(\alpha,\sigma^2)}
\\
&=\frac{p(t,\sigma^2|w,\alpha)}{p(\sigma^2|\alpha)}\frac{p(w|\alpha)}{p(t|\alpha,\sigma^2)}.
\end{align}
However, I am not sure why (*) should hold. I feel there must be some hidden assumptions but I couldn't figure this out. Any help would be highly appreciated.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I figured this out.
Note that the following relations are assumed:
$$
p(t|w,\alpha,\sigma^2) = p(t|w,\sigma^2), \quad
p(\alpha,\sigma^2) = p(\alpha)p(\sigma^2), \quad
p(w,\alpha,\sigma^2) = p(w,\alpha)p(\sigma^2),
$$
which also gives $p(\sigma^2|\alpha) = p(\sigma^2)$.
Hence, it can be checked that
$$
\frac{p(t,\sigma^2|w,\alpha)}{p(\sigma^2|\alpha)}
= p(t|w,\alpha,\sigma^2)\frac{p(w,\alpha,\sigma^2)}{p(w,\alpha)p(\sigma^2)} = p(t|w,\alpha,\sigma^2)
= p(t|w,\sigma^2).
$$